# Not able to start redis server on Mac M1

Tags: macos, redis, apple-m1

I am using a Macbook Pro M1 and I  am trying to start my server through Intellij

-- Added from the comments below --

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME 
redis-ser 3387 josephantony 6u IPv4 0x9c37a0d6c1c8e2c9 0t0 TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN) redis-ser 3387 josephantony 7u IPv6 0x9c37a0d6ba1e9219 0t0 TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
```

-- End of comment --

And getting this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'redisServer' defined in class path
> resource [com/sensei/gls/config/EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [redis.embedded.RedisServer]: Factory method 'redisServer'
> threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
> start redis server. Check logs for details.   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 132 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [redis.embedded.RedisServer]: Factory method 'redisServer'
> threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't
> start redis server. Check logs for details.   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
> ... 145 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Can't start redis server. Check logs for details.     at
> redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.awaitRedisServerReady(AbstractRedisInstance.java:62)
> at
> redis.embedded.AbstractRedisInstance.start(AbstractRedisInstance.java:39)
> at redis.embedded.RedisServer.start(RedisServer.java:9)     at
> com.sensei.gls.config.EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.redisServer(EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.java:34)
> at
> com.sensei.gls.config.EmbeddedRedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de8352da.CGLIB$redisServer$0()
> at
> com.sensei.gls.config.EmbeddedRedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de8352da$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ccaa38a4.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
> at
> com.sensei.gls.config.EmbeddedRedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de8352da.redisServer()
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ... 146 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you set up `redis` server in your system. But I followed the instructions from [spring guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-redis/#scratch) (also installed it with rosetta2 enabled terminal), and it's working fine.

[image: redis-server-in-m1-mac-using-brew]

Comment: I am still getting the same error. could we connect ? and i can show you the error

Comment: Sure. share all the information related to your redis setup

Comment: COMMAND    PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
redis-ser 3387 josephantony    6u  IPv4 0x9c37a0d6c1c8e2c9      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)
redis-ser 3387 josephantony    7u  IPv6 0x9c37a0d6ba1e9219      0t0  TCP localhost:6379 (LISTEN)